# Flash object function is undefined in my JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, actionscript, undefined, externalinterface

I've an asp.net website, where i have a flash object embedded. Flash object have some functions registered via ExternalInterface, so it should be accessible from JavaScript. And they are, but only when i call it when site completely loaded and i trigger some events (click etc)
But when i try to access any of this function from the script block, i have an error that i call an underfined function.

This script placed at the end of document, at this moment flashGame object not underfinded, but his functions is underfined.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var flashObj = document.getElementById("flashGame");
            // AdLoaded is underfined at this moment. 
            flashObj.AdLoaded();
            // Also tried this, no luck
            $(document).ready(function () {
                flashObj.AdLoaded();
            });  
</script>
```

AdLoadedis underfined in both cases. 
P.S. 
And if i place a breakpoint at begin of the script it seems then all works ok, function AdLoaded() not underfined.
What i miss?
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `ready` block but the element is not in the body yet, so `getElementById` likely returns null,

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var flashObj = document.getElementById("flashGame");  
    flashObj.AdLoaded();
});
```

Note, that document.ready is not an indication that the flash finished loading, just that the DOM is ready, so you might have to even do:

```
$(window).on("load",function () {
    var flashObj = document.getElementById("flashGame");
    flashObj.AdLoaded();
});
```

Comment: Indeed, i understood where is the problem, so when flash object in DOM is ready but it's external interface not initialized yet, so i get an undefinded value. Thanks Benjamin!